# How to apply texture globally on a set of objects from a particular position?

Tags: opengl, projection, texture-mapping, lighting, texture2d

I know very little of OpenGL.

I want to apply a 2D **texture globally** onto the scene in OPENGL 3.1 as in figure in [this link](http://picpaste.com/Untitled-p4Ymy27C.png) as if the texture is viewed from the point **P**.

While the texture projection parameters e.g. focal length **f** , position **P**, etc. all are known, how can I do this in OpenGL, so that I can view it from another position?

N.B. The lighting and texture pasting need to be of the form GL_MODULATE.

Comment: Are you trying to do this with the legacy fixed function pipeline, or are you using shaders?

Comment: @RetoKoradi: fixed function pipeline... I have no basic programming idea in GLSL!

Comment: Look for projected textures (e.g. https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/code/samples/mjktips/projtex/index.html). Also note that fixed pipeline is deprecated in OpenGL 3.1.

Comment: @Archie: Thanks! I made this with **Shadow Mapping** and **RGBA Texture Mapping** simultaneously using **Projective Texture Mapping** and **glActiveTexture()** functions following [this](http://www.paulsprojects.net/tutorials/smt/smt.html), [this](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/code/samples/mjktips/projtex/index.html) and [this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=770639&seqNum=5).

Answer (score 0):

With the fixed pipeline, this can be achieved by applying a projection matrix to the texture coordinates.

Aside from the very commonly used values of `GL_MODELVIEW` and `GL_PROJECTION`, `glMatrixMode()` also supports a value of `GL_TEXTURE`, which exposes a mechanism for applying arbitrary transformations to texture coordinates.

In this case, you can use the original world coordinates as the input texture coordinates. So if you used:

```
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, coord);
```

you use the same for the texture coordinates:

```
glTexCoordPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, coord);
```

Then you set up view and projection transformations very similarly to the way you do for the primary view/projection. Keep in mind that transformations are specified in the reverse order of being applied. So the sequence would be something like this:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);

// Projection maps to [-1.0, 1.0] range, while texture coordinates are in
// range [0.0, 1.0]. Translate/scale to adjust for this.
glScalef(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
glTranslatef(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

// Apply projection.
gluPerspective(...)

// Apply view transformation, using P as eye point.
gluLookAt(...);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

Comment: Using the vertex coords as texcoords and applying a texture matrix should work, but there is a more direct appraoch for this in the fixed function pipeline: the texture coordinate generation using [`glTexGen*()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glTexGen.xml) with `GL_EYE_LINEAR` mode. One needs to specify a matrix transfroming from eye space to the tex coords as 4 vectors via the `GL_EYE_PLANE` paramater for each tex coord.

Comment: (continuing last comment) The advantage is that one does not need to change the matrix when the model matrix is to be changed, which the approach described here requires, as the vertex coords are object space.

Comment: @derhass:Thanks! Now I need to add two projective textures: one for the **shadow** and other is the **RGBA** texture from the same point **P**. My question is how to add two (different) textures now?

Comment: @derhass That doesn't really seem any simpler to me. Quite to the contrary. You would have to calculate the full matrix for the view/projection transformation from the different "view point" yourself. And starting in eye space, you would have to apply the inverse of the original view matrix first, because you only want to use the model matrix from the original transformation. Looks very cumbersome to me. But maybe you can write an answer to explain it?

Comment: @SMH The texture matrix stack is per texture unit. So you can do the above for each texture after making the corresponding texture unit active. But once you start using more than one texture, I would **really really** recommend to start using shaders. It will be much simpler and more flexible that way.

Comment: @derhass: Thanks I made it using `glActiveTexture()` functions.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: Thanks! I made it using `glActiveTexture()` functions.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: Well. My point is that your sentence "In this case, you can use the original world coordinates as the input texture coordinates." isn't really correct. These are object space coordinates, not world coordinates. In a typical scene, one uses a single view transform but a different model transforms per object. In that scenario, the `glTexGen` approach requires you to set up the transform matrix "eye to texcoords" only once (when the view changes), and not when the model transform is changed, while in your appraoch, you'll have to track that model change in the texture matrix.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: As for writing an answer: that would require me to read the details of the fixed function texcoord generation again, which I have long forgotten - and don't really care about anymore ;). So I totally agree to the advice that shaders should be used here...